# Customized WooCommerce messages removes onClick event on HTML tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I've overridden `notices/success.php` template file, modifying the content this way:

```
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
        <span>
            <?php
            echo wc_kses_notice( $message );
            ?>
        </span>
        <div onClick="alert('LOL')">TEST</div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I now load the page, the elements are all generated but my onClick is removed:

```
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert"> <span> Kontodetails erfolgreich geändert. </span><div>TEST</div></div>
```

Why is this happening and how can I keep my onClick in every div or span within this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this problem, instead of using an onClick event on the `<div>` tag, you should use a jQuery script:

**1) The overridden template** `notices/success.php` file *(excerpt)*:

```
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
        <span>
        <?php
            echo wc_kses_notice( $message );
        ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="message-click">TEST</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**2) The jQuery script:**

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'message_onclick_event');
function message_onclick_event() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document.body).on('click', 'div.message-click', function(){
            alert('LOL');
        })
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme), or in an external registered JS file.

**3) The html output:**

```
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
    <span>Hello World</span>
</div>
<div class="message-click">TEST</div>
```

**4) A screenshot** *(when clicking on "TEST")*:

[image]

Comment: This truly works but the big question is, why I can't do it the other way?

Comment: @Mr.Jo There are some mysteries that is better to keep in the box :) … May be you have heard about JS events and Ajax?